# Laravel and surveyjs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.6, surveyjs

I'm relatively comfortable with laravel, but know very very little about javascript and npm in general... just to set some context.

I am building an app where I now require a "library of forms" to be filled out. So I'm thinking that I should leverage the expertise of others, and take advantage of what appears to be quite an impressive bit of work, in the form of SurveyJS. https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library

I'm probably making a total dog's breakfast of these different concepts, so bear with me please.

So whilst I've got the npm thing running smoothly, I'm not sure I understand the whole webpack compilation thing (yet).

Can you explain to me...

- My plan is to have a number of "surveys" defined suitably for the surveyjs "engine". The logic I'm seeing is laravel app eventually pulls "a survey" and passes it to a view to be "executed".
- The surveyJs librarys will use that model amd provide the results back to the laravel app - I'll pickup the results in a controller and deal with them.

If this is a suitable approach, then what are these choices about? https://github.com/surveyjs

If I take https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-php (because it's the closest thing I can find to php/laravel then first step is to install docker. I'm a little confused about why I would be installing more "infrastructure" when I'm actually looking for the libraries necessary.

I don't understand why what I'm thinking as a very clever bit of javascript seems to want it's own "infrastructure" - docker / webpacks / etc. And then there's still the whole laravel `mix` thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main repo has dists for several different js frameworks, the editor  repo is just that - only the core surveyjs lib - and the other repos are sample apps, a base project template and extras you may not need.

JavaScript has become a whole ecosystem in and of itself: building with rollup,  webpack,  parcel, brunch, gulp? For which framework, if any,  Angular, react, vue, jquery, vanilla or a little bit of a and a little of b? What are you targeting, browsers, node, both, making an electron app? Using es6? Newer? Typescript?

Basically you're seeing surveyjs want infrastructure because they have answered the above questions. Welcome to javascript :)

Comment: Ouch... no wonder I'm baffled :). Right now I'm thinking jquery and taregting browsers... if that makes sense?